# SQL view and rename different values in a column into one another different name in value for correlated duplicate values

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Pkey               KName            Group
-----------------------------------------------
PC-229             History         Ancient
PC-229             History         Self
PC-229             History         Load
PC-228             History         Ancient
PC-234             History         Load
PC-235             History         Self
```

I need a query to out put the above, the query need to output a view for the above and change the name of Group field values to "All" for the duplicated values in Pkey. so for above we have (PC-229 duplicated, but the correlated values in Group is different so I need them in one "All" value with only one return of PC-229), so I need the results something like below from above table;

```
Pkey               KName            Group
-----------------------------------------------
PC-229             History          All
PC-228             History         Ancient
PC-234             History         Load
PC-235             History         Self
```

Please advise!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select pkey, history,
       (case when min(group) = max(group) then min(group)
             else '**All**'
        end) new_group
from t
group by pkey, history;
```

I'm not sure if `history` should be part of the aggregation.  It always has the same value in your example, so you can remove it from the `group by` and use `max(history)` instead.

Comment: sorry is that works with Oracle queries ? and what is the purpose of that new_group?

Comment: @HKLM . . . This should work with Oracle, although I would rename `group` to something else, because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: Well Actually, I put the above table which is this lately a results from another query, its resulted from  
'SELECT JI.PKEY, JP.KName, JC.Group
FROM Jumara.JumaraIssue JI
INNER JOIN Jumara.NODE_A JN
ON JI.ID = JN.SNODE_ID
INNER JOIN Jumara.COMP JC
ON JN.SI_NODE_ID = JC.ID
INNER JOIN Jumara.PROJECT JP
ON JP.ID = JC.PROJECT'

so this is why I asked if that works on Oracle, I'm not sure if I add the above as subquery as from your CASE condition , but not sure how that fits in! Any idea?

Comment: Ok I was able to tweak the query, and able to run it, thanks for your help, it worked. 
Cheers

Comment: I was able to re-prouce the main query with your CASe sub query, I was asking another question out of this, how you can identify another query to count fields under Group by Kname, for exampel from above table I want to know how many 'All' is created for History, and how many 'Ancient' is created for History too, and by the way under that Kname column ther is also other values rather than History, so here as I mentioned How to calculate History for 'All' and for 'Ancient' and so on? Thanks